# SQL NOT IN Subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, subquery

So I have the following query (see below) that I wrote for a co-worker:

```
SELECT
        t.tender_id as "Tender ID",
        t.check_number as "Check Number",
        t.check_type_id as "Check Type",
        t.server_id as "Server ID",
        t.cashier_id as "Cashier ID",
        t.terminal_id as "Terminal ID",
        t.tendered_date_time as "Tendered Date and Time",
        t.tender_amount as "Tender Amount",
        t.change_amount as "Change Amount",
        g.account_name as "Account Name",
        g.account_number as "Account Number"
FROM CheckTender AS t
INNER JOIN AcountActivity AS g
        ON t.check_number = g.check_number
WHERE t.tender_id NOT in (5,14,4,9,15,16);
```

A check number can have multiple tender_IDs.  So, for example, you could have three rows for check number 20001, all with different tender_IDs.

Initially, he just wanted any entries where the tender_id was `5,14,4,9,15,16` removed. But then we discovered that we need to modify the where criteria.

It needs to be updated so that IF a check number has a tender ID of `5,14,4,9,15,16`, ALL instances of that check number are removed.  I know this is most likely a subquery, but I have been beating my head against it all morning without being able to figure it out. :(

Comment: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Comment: So find the check numbers that fall under those tender ID's and just omit those check numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` for this:

```
SELECT
        t.tender_id as "Tender ID",
        t.check_number as "Check Number",
        t.check_type_id as "Check Type",
        t.server_id as "Server ID",
        t.cashier_id as "Cashier ID",
        t.terminal_id as "Terminal ID",
        t.tendered_date_time as "Tendered Date and Time",
        t.tender_amount as "Tender Amount",
        t.change_amount as "Change Amount",
        g.account_name as "Account Name",
        g.account_number as "Account Number"
FROM CheckTender AS t
INNER JOIN AcountActivity AS g
        ON t.check_number = g.check_number
WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT * FROM CheckTender WHERE check_number =  t.check_number
                    AND tender_id in (5,14,4,9,15,16))
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (untested)?

```
SELECT
        t.tender_id as "Tender ID",
        t.check_number as "Check Number",
        t.check_type_id as "Check Type",
        t.server_id as "Server ID",
        t.cashier_id as "Cashier ID",
        t.terminal_id as "Terminal ID",
        t.tendered_date_time as "Tendered Date and Time",
        t.tender_amount as "Tender Amount",
        t.change_amount as "Change Amount",
        g.account_name as "Account Name",
        g.account_number as "Account Number"
FROM CheckTender AS t
INNER JOIN AcountActivity AS g
        ON t.check_number = g.check_number
LEFT JOIN (SELECT check_number  FROM CheckTender WHERE tender_id in (5,14,4,9,15,16)) t2 on t.tender_id = t2.tender_id
WHERE t2.tender_id is null
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it with a window function:

```
select *
from (SELECT
             t.tender_id as "Tender ID",
             t.check_number as "Check Number",
             t.check_type_id as "Check Type",
             t.server_id as "Server ID",
             t.cashier_id as "Cashier ID",
             t.terminal_id as "Terminal ID",
             t.tendered_date_time as "Tendered Date and Time",
             t.tender_amount as "Tender Amount",
             t.change_amount as "Change Amount",
             g.account_name as "Account Name",
             g.account_number as "Account Number",
             MAX(case when t.tender_id in (5,14,4,9,15,16) then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by t.check_number) as HasBadTender
      FROM CheckTender AS t
      INNER JOIN AcountActivity AS g
                 ON t.check_number = g.check_number
     ) t
where HasBadTender = 0
```

This works with SQL Server 2005 and greater.  For earlier versions, you'll need some form of join or correlated subquery.

A slight variation on your original where clause also works:

```
WHERE t.check_number not in (select check_number from CheckTender where tender in (5,14,4,9,15,16))
```